# in php can an sql injection possibly make it through is_numeric function?

Tags: php, mysql

could i safely assume (if i'm just GETting an id number) that is_numeric is good enough to thwart sql injection attacks? or is there sql injection methods that can pass through is_numeric?

Comment: It's probably safe.  But that's not a reason to avoid using prepared statements (PDO).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd be better served to just do:

`$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int) $_GET['id'] : 0;`

This way you can avoid the `is_numeric` function overhead. Either method is sufficient to avoid injection, though (as long as you do something to the data if `is_numeric` returns FALSE). The ternary operator also makes sure you don't get an E_NOTICE if the $_GET variable in question doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you describe how much higher the overhead of the function call is compared to the ternary operator?

Comment: @KingCrunch: You don't necessarily want to use this method.  It offers no chance to validate the input.

Comment: @KingCrunch I know the 'overhead' argument can start religious nerd wars, but I fail to see how avoiding an unecessary function call can ever be bad.

Comment: Another sidenote: The last statement "ternary operator omits E_NOTICE" is wrong. // Its "bad" (not "bad" in the meaning of "bad", but more like "little bit not that clean"), because you cannot properly validate the values. `id=hello` results in `$id = 0`, which may be a valid id, or not, but its not "broken" like I would expect it.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth The method is to avoid SQL injection, not validate input. It addresses the procedure outlined in the question.

Comment: @rdlowrey: I understand.  I'm reminding the OP that there may be things he's forgetting about...

Comment: @KingCrunch In my haste to submit I forgot `isset` in the ternary operation -- corrected. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @KingCrunch: Calling a function leaves the possibility that this function is faulty. In contrast, the possibility that the cast will not yield an integer can be neglected.

Comment: Seems a little bit too paranoid to mistrust such simple and builtin functions ;) But I see your point.

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't. However, remind, that for example `is_numeric('0xaf5') == true`, thus its maybe not enough according what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `intval` or `floatval`.